# ASP.net AsyncFileUpload: How to send Exceptions messages from the 'UploadedComplete' event to the client function 'uploadError'

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, asyncfileupload

I've been following this [tutorial](http://technico.qnownow.com/using-asyncfileupload-control-in-asp-net-ajax/) , but I got a problem.

If an exception is thrown in the UploadedComplete event

```
protected void AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string importPath = MapPath("~/docs/imports/");
                string filename = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss") + Path.GetFileName(e.FileName);

                //pass filename to front end;
                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "newfile"
                    , "window.parent.$find('" + AsyncFileUpload1.ClientID + "').newFileName='" + filename + "';", true);

                AsyncFileUpload1.SaveAs(importPath + filename);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "size", "top.$get(\"" + lblUploadStatus.ClientID + "\").innerHTML = 'There was an Error Processing the Request : Error " + ex.Message.ToString() + "';", true);

            }
        }
```

I want the exception message shown in the label that is below the AsyncFileUpload control.

I thought that using a try catch and passing the message using  ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock would be enough and that message will be passed to this client side function

```
function uploadError(sender, args) {
            var errmsg = args.get_errorMessage();
            updateUploadStatus("error", "There was Error Uploading the file. Error :" + errmsg);
        }
```

But even if a exception is thrown, the controls ignores it and show a successful message.

I also noticed that the status parameter in this function never gets updated. It is always "success"

```
function updateUploadStatus(status, message) {
            var uploadstatlbl = $("span[id$='lblUploadStatus']");
            uploadstatlbl.html(message);
            if (status == "error") {
                uploadstatlbl.removeClass("spansuccess").addClass("spanerror");
            } else {
                uploadstatlbl.removeClass("spanerror").addClass("spansuccess");
            }
        }
```

Do you have any idea what can be causing this???

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that to say the function uploadError is not entered?

Comment: If you mean that the function uploadError is never called when a exception in the UploadedComplete event  is thrown, then the answer is Yes.

Comment: For me, if the server event UploadedComplete is entered, the uploadError function on client side will never be called. As documented in the site http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AsyncFileUpload/AsyncFileUpload.aspx AsyncFileUpload does have a server event which is called UploadedFileError. The file is uploaded to the session(I think) succesfully if the UploadedComplete is triggered. So what you have done in try catch is to save the file from session to the '/docs/imports/' folder.

Comment: @Sawyer OK I understand that, but what about if ,for example, the `'/docs/imports/'` doesn't exist?? Even in that case the exception is completely ignored and a success message is shown.

Comment: @Sawyer Or if I want to check whether the excel file I'm uploading has a certain format , so it doesn't have that format instead of saving a useless file I just throw a custom exception or some kind of notification, informing the user about this.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but thought of posting this in case some body come here searching for this

Since `AsyncFileUpload` do it's magic in an `iframe` you should use `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` instead of `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock`

Answer (score 0):

I think the prerequisite to use these two client side fonctions is whether a file is successfully uploaded or not but not the after examination. So if you want to send the Exception message to user, like the format of excel. It will be better to do some workarouds. Because I don't have enough time to realize this, some advices and ideas will be listed below for you if I am correct.

**Firstly** a function js should be added in the page,

```
function validfile(status, message){
            var uploadstatlbl = $("span[id$='LabelMessage']");
            uploadstatlbl.html(message);
            if (status == "notvalid") {
                uploadstatlbl.removeClass("spansuccess").addClass("spanerror");
            } else {
                uploadstatlbl.removeClass("spanerror").addClass("spansuccess");
            }
}
```

**Secondly** modify your code,

```
protected void AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
            {
                try
                {
                    string importPath = MapPath("~/docs/imports/");
                    string filename = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss") +                      Path.GetFileName(e.FileName);

                    //pass filename to front end;
                    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "newfile"
                        , "window.parent.$find('" + AsyncFileUpload1.ClientID + "').newFileName='" + filename + "';", true);

                    AsyncFileUpload1.SaveAs(importPath + filename);
                    string script = "validfile('valide', 'The file is uploaded successfully');";
                    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "size", script, true);}
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // I didn't test it in visual studio, it means we will call the method js after postback
                    string script = "validfile('notvalide', '" + ex.Message + "');";
                    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "size", script, true);
                }
            }
```

**Finally** add updatepanel and register asynctrigger,

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="" runat="" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="AsyncFileUpload1" EventName="UploadedCompleted" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="LabelMessage" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The code pseudo means that the event UploadCompletd will update LabelMessage in UpdatePanel and trigger the function validfile.

I am not sure if these code could be executed directly.

I adviced you to use firebug to test if the funciton `js` could be called after file uploaded.

Comment: I tried your code, but I couldn't make it work :( I have also thought of using something like this `httpResponse.Clear();`                 `httpResponse.StatusCode = 500;` , but I don't know how to write in the args.get_errorMessage();

Comment: there must be a way of calling the `uploadError` function